# Firebase automatically collected event: user_engagement not show in the portal

Tags: firebase-analytics

In the firebase documents about [Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en)

There is one event named: user_engagement, the definition is : periodically, while the app is in the foreground.

But I didn't see this event in the event report, other automatical events such as first_open, app_remove are there.

Answer (score 3):

The user_engagement event fuels the reporting of User Engagement metrics in the dashboard.